# Input with Postfix Button in Top-Bar using Zurb Foundation

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to get a Text-Input with a Postfix Button in my Top-Bar using Zurb-Foundation as explained here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php#btopCode

However, using the following code the button always ends up below the input:

```
<nav class="top-bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="name"><h1>Home</h1></li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section>

        <ul class="left">
            <li class="search">
                <form class="collapse">
                    <input type="text">
                    <button type="submit" class="secondary radius button">Search</button>
                </form>
            </li>

            <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a href="#">Item1</a>

                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

like this:
[image]

Comment: I put the form outside of the `top-bar` and used `position: absolute` to make it show up in the right spot.  Not responsive, but I hide the form for small screens, so it works for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the form inside of a drop down. I don't think it will work directly on the nav bar it self. This is not documented well on the site and could use some improvement.

```
 <nav class="top-bar">
        <ul>
            <li class="name"><h1>Home</h1></li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <section>

            <ul class="left">
               <li class="has-dropdown">
                   <a href="#">Search</a>
                       <ul class="dropdown">
                           <li class="search">
                                <form>
                                  <input type="search">
                                  <button type="submit" class="secondary radius button">Search</button>
                                </form>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Item1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I think this worked to some extent, but in the end I gave up and went with twitter bootstrap instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, if you take a look at the documentation, you'll see how to implement it properly.

It's at the bottom of the example snippet:

```
  <li class="has-form">
    <form>
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-8 columns">
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="small-4 columns">
          <a href="#" class="alert button">Search</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </li>
  <li class="divider show-for-small"></li>
  <li class="has-form">
    <a class="button" href="#">Button!</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't work inside of the top-bar in Foundation 5.  The prefix/postfix doesn't get sized right.

Comment: This is not correct.  Prefix/postfix do not get added properly.

Answer (score 1):

For Foundation 5, this is how I solved the problem:

```
nav.top-bar {
    $height: 1.8rem;
    $textFontSize: 0.8rem;

    .prefix, .postfix {
        /* So even though you can embed forms in the top nav, they get jankified.
           WOW.  This is kinda lame. */
        height: $height;
        line-height: $height;
        font-size: $textFontSize;

        i { 
            font-size: 0.8rem;
        }
    }

    .prefix {
        margin-top: 7px; 
    }

    .postfix {
        padding: 0;
    }

    input {
        font-size: $textFontSize;
        height: $height;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you [Search input in top-bar foundation cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894656/search-input-in-top-bar-foundation-cut-off) and managed to make it work after a while by float everything to the left and adding some !important and the inputs.
What I found in foundation docs wasn't helpful but anyways, this did the trick:

```
.left .search .button { float:left; width:50px; margin-left:5px;}
.search input {width:200px;float:left;top:5px;}
.search form {float:left !important; width:450px !important;}
```