# Search input in top-bar foundation cut off

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have a similar issue to someone there: [Input with Postfix Button in Top-Bar using Zurb Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099087/input-with-postfix-button-in-top-bar-using-zurb-foundation) who was offered an alternative more than an answer. (The second answer on the page is what is described in foundation docs there http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html, I've tried and it isn't working either, see the second input in my header).

The issue can be seen here: http://odesktestanswers2013.com/Metareviewer/index.php
Basically, the submit input won't float next to its text input.

Can anybody recommend a fix or help me figure out what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to make it work after a while by floating everything to the left and adding some !important to the inputs.
What I found in foundation docs wasn't helpful but anyways their "has-form" class is useless, this did the trick:

```
.left .search .button { float:left; width:50px; margin-left:5px;}
.search input {width:200px;float:left;top:5px;}
.search form {float:left !important; width:450px !important;}
```